# Valgrind warning: unknown option '--track-origins=yes'

Tags: r, valgrind

I want to run `valgrind` with the option `'--track-origins=yes'` because `valgrind` gives me the message `'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)'`. But when I run

```
R -d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=20" --vanilla --track-origins=yes
```

I get the warning

> unknown option '--track-origins=yes'

How can I run `valgrind` with this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
R -d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=20 --track-origins=yes" --vanilla
```

You need to feed options of `valgrind` inside `""`, otherwise they will be seen as options to `R`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Saved my evening !